# AQL cutting off data when querying through console

Tags: aerospike, aql

Trying to query some bin for some record through AQL, however, the data is cut off.

Any ideas how to make AQL print full data?

```
aql> select tokens from user.users where pk='some_pk'
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tokens                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MAP('{"93836":"external-jfbl8squ-zWLoOuBgXD-test::1527455663", "39720":"external-jfbl8squ-UZWvWVMjtc-test::1527455663", "40870":"external-jfbl8squ-kIFcZKdimg-test::1527455663", "70065":"external-jfbl8squ-PezniJBRgE-test::1527455663", "36903":"external-jf |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 secs)
```

As you can see, the data is not finished at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right after posted this question, I tried starting AQL with "-o json" and it works.

aql> select partner_tokens from user.users where pk='cfef295b-dbd6-4f5f-8ad6-b0332c950772'

```
[
  {
    "tokens": {
      "93836": "external-jfbl8squ-zWLoOuBgXD-test::1527455663",
      "39720": "external-jfbl8squ-UZWvWVMjtc-test::1527455663",
      "40870": "external-jfbl8squ-kIFcZKdimg-test::1527455663",
      "70065": "external-jfbl8squ-PezniJBRgE-test::1527455663",
      "36903": "external-jfbl8squ-yYSCVcZeuF-test::1527455663",
      "78608": "external-jfbl8squ-vYukUUHCSa-test::1527455663",
      "50785": "external-jfbl8squ-kOonwnEZiL-test::1527455663"
    }
  }
]
```